# Android error with debugger on eclipse

Tags: android, debugging, android-asynctask

I try to write this Thread in Android application.

```
        class RunnableTemperatura  extends AsyncTask<Setting, String, ParametriAmbientali>{
        @Override
        protected ParametriAmbientali doInBackground(Setting... arg0) {

            try {
                setting = arg0[0];
                ParametriAmbientali par= null;
                par= arduino.getTemperatura(setting.getUrl()+"/"+suffissoTemperatura);
                return par;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("OnPostExcecute thread Temperatura", "Errore",e);
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ParametriAmbientali par) {
            try {
                //par= arduino.getTemperatura(setting.getUrl()+"/"+suffissoTemperatura);
                textValTemperatura.setText(par.getTemperatura().toString());
                textUmidita.setText(par.getUmidita().toString());
                Thread.sleep(60*1000*setting.getSecondThreadTemperature());
                new RunnableTemperatura().execute(setting);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("OnPostExcecute thread Temperatura", "Errore",e);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... item) {
            //dialog.setMessage(item[0]);
        }
```

This AsyncTask found, but if I execute a debug in this code

```
    try {
                    setting = arg0[0];
                    ParametriAmbientali par= null;
                    par= arduino.getTemperatura(setting.getUrl()+"/"+suffissoTemperatura);
                    return par;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("OnPostExcecute thread Temperatura", "Errore",e);
                }
           return null;
```

I notice a bug, the debugger don't execute never "return par;" but return null and I don't have any error, so when I execute debugger on OnPostExecute method the object ParametriAmbientali is populate correctly.

Can we help me?

Reguards

Comment: may be arduino.getTemperatura() return null

Comment: No, I try to change my code, so I have write this: ParametriAmbientali par= new ParametriAmbientali(); return par; but this method return null;

Comment: Put a breakpoint in wher eyou log and see if it stops there. If it does you know an exception happens. It can also be an idea to type in e.printStackTrace(). If you get no exception then obviously getTemperatura returns null.